# Unable to upload CDAP custom plugin in Datafusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am trying to upload http-sink plugin from Datafusion upload button. I cloned the http-sink repository and I made few very minimal changes and packaged it as a JAR. Now when I try to upload the JAR and the JSON files using upload plugin button, I am getting the following error:

> 'artifact:default.http-plugins.1.3.0-SNAPSHOT' was not found

Can anyone help me on how to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

Currently [Data Fusion](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion) that based purely on [CDAP](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/) platfrom, represents a variety of the desired features, extending the basic functionality within a particular [plugins](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/3.6.0/en/hydrator-manual/concepts-design.html#plugins).

When you need to explore your plugin and use it in a dedicated [*pipeline*](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/4.3.3/en/developer-manual/pipelines/index.html) or [*stream*](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/3.6.0/en/developers-manual/building-blocks/streams.html) source, plugin essentially needs to be deployed to the parent `cdap-data-pipeline` or `cdap-data-streams` artifacts respectively.

Basically [Artifact](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/3.5.3/en/developers-manual/building-blocks/artifacts.html#artifacts) is as packaged file produced by some software development process, which contains application related properties and dependencies, furthermore it should contain unique identifiers like `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`.

Looking at the issue you've reported, I would recommend to start research from the first build phase, compiling code and packaging it to `JAR` and `JSON` files. The main sensitive contributor here is `pom.xml` file, as it contains the significant information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project, knowing also as [POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#What_is_a_POM).

A few things that can be checked:

1. What was a custom configuration applied to the origin `http-plugin`
   source code, and whether you consider any changes caused to the
   native code by reflecting them to `pom.xml` file;
2. Check if the correct repository is specified in the `pom.xml` from
   which the package was downloaded originally;
3. How did you compile the source code in Maven, i.e: `mvn clean
   install` or `mvn clean package`?;
4. Check Maven compilation output, seeking for any suspicious outputs.

I did a quick test, cloning HTTP sink plugin [repo](https://github.com/data-integrations/http) and following the implementation steps in the guide section; I built JAR and JSON files and was able to successfully deploy `http-plugins 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT` in my Data Fusion instance.

Comment: I followed the same procedure and still i am getting the same issue. The custom configuration is I just want to add few error codes and build it as plugin and use in my system. I didn't touched any other code.